# Calculate $\int ^{\pi}_0\ln(1+\alpha \cos x) dx$

Tags: calculus, functions

Calculate $$\int ^{\pi}_0\ln(1+\alpha \cos x) dx$$ for $|\alpha|<1$.

I tried Let 
$$f(\alpha)=\int ^{\pi}_0\ln(1+\alpha \cos x) dx$$ 
then
$$\frac{df}{d\alpha}=\int^{\pi}_0\frac{\cos x}{1+\alpha \cos x}dx$$
But it seems need some other tricks...

Then I tried 
$$
\begin{align}
\int^{\pi}_0\ln(1+\alpha\cos x) dx &=\int^{\pi}_0[\ln(1+\alpha\cos x)-\ln1]dx\\
&=\int^{\pi}_0[\ln(1+y\cos x)]^{y=\alpha}_{y=0}dx\\
& =\int^{\pi}_0[\int^{\alpha}_0\frac{\cos x}{1+y\cos x}dy]dx
\end{align}
$$

Any help? Thanks~

Comment: The very last integral is straightfoward to compute through Weierstrass' substitution $x=2\arctan\frac{t}{2}$: $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos x}{1+\alpha\cos x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{\alpha}-\frac{\pi}{\alpha\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}} $$

Comment: @Peter The OP is differentiating wrt to $\;\alpha\;$ , **not to** $\;x\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio Didn't notice that, sorry.

Comment: It follows that $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(1+\alpha\cos x)\,dx = \pi\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}{2}\right).$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Why does Wolfram then fail to calculate the integral ? When I tried to calculate the indefinite integral, Wolfram returned a very complicated function expression containing $li$-functions and when I tried to calculate the definite integral, it didn't return any result. Could the reason be that Wolfram also considers complex $\alpha$ , in which case the integral might not converge ?

Comment: @Peter: that is probably the reason. The analytic continuation of such a function has a complicated structure related with the dilogarithm, but we are just interested in the real function defined over $(-1,1)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio More details? I tried your substitution, did not get simpler, may be somewhere I got wrong. Any tricks involves here?

Comment: @NanLi: I actually found and posted a simpler way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos x}{1+\alpha\cos x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{\alpha}-\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{1+\alpha\cos x}\tag{1}$$
and 
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{1+\alpha\cos x} = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{1}{1+\alpha\cos x}+\frac{1}{1-\alpha\cos x}\right)\,dx \tag{2}$$
hence
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos x}{1+\alpha\cos x}\,dx =\frac{\pi}{\alpha}-\frac{2}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{1-\alpha^2\cos^2(x)}\tag{3}$$
and by setting $x=\arctan t$ in the last integral,
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos x}{1+\alpha\cos x}\,dx =\frac{\pi}{\alpha}-\frac{2}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^2-\alpha^2}\tag{4}$$
hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{\pi}\log(1+\alpha\cos x)\,dx &=& \pi\int_{0}^{\alpha}\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}-\frac{1}{\alpha\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}\right)\,d\alpha\\[0.2cm]&=&\color{red}{\pi\,\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}{2}\right)}.\tag{5}\end{eqnarray*} $$

Comment: How did you get the (1) ?

Comment: @NanLi: $$\frac{\cos x}{1+\alpha\cos x} = \frac{1}{\alpha}\cdot\frac{\alpha\cos x}{1+\alpha\cos x} = \frac{1}{\alpha}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+\alpha\cos x}\right).$$